# After installing Quasar to an existing Vue project, how do you use quasar components in the project?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to use quasar in a pre-existing Vue 3 project. When I try using something as simple as `<q-btn">` using the quasar-framework import, the page blanks out? There's no /quasar.conf.js file only an quasar-user-options.js with a config and plugins object in it. Please help I'm new to Vue and Quasar.

quasar-user-options:

```
import './styles/quasar.scss'
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css'

// To be used on app.use(Quasar, { ... })
export default {
  config: {},
  plugins: {
  }
}
```

AddEmployee.vue

```
<template>
    <Navbar/>
    <h1>Add Employee</h1>
    <q-btn color="primary" label="With Tooltip" class="q-mt-md">
      <q-tooltip class="bg-accent">I'm a tooltip</q-tooltip>
    </q-btn>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar.vue'
import Quasar from "quasar-framework/dist/quasar.mat.esm";
import "quasar-framework/dist/umd/quasar.mat.css";

Vue.use(Quasar);

export default {
components: {
      Navbar,
      QBtn
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: If you want to add Quasar capabilities directly to your existing Vue app, you would need to use the official CLI. I think the way you're importing it would only work if you want to have a Quasar-Vue3 app in parallel to your existing Vue3 app.  Did you add Quasar with the Quasar Vue CLI plugin as instructed (https://quasar.dev/start/vue-cli-plugin) and did you make sure you had the latest Vue CLI before installing the Quasar plugin? What options did you select when/if you did `vue add quasar`? If you're using the cli plugin I'd recommend first try adding it to the default vue template.

Comment: Yes I added quasar using the Quasar Vue Cli as instructed by the link. In the settings I didn't allow Quasar to replace App.vue etc. Then I selected Sass with SCSS syntax and I selected yes to rtl support. How to add the cli plugin to the default vue template? @InvisibleGorilla